# External monitor affects Chrome font clarity?

Tags: html, google-chrome, font-face, font-awesome, text-rendering

I'm having trouble with font clarity in Google Chrome.  I am developing a website at www.transitioncville.org using @font-face web fonts and FontAwesome to render text and icons in my navbar.  When I have my external monitor plugged in (but the Chrome window is on my macbook display) and I navigate to my website, I see clear, crisp text/icons:

[image: Crisp text]

If I unplug my external monitor I continue to get clear, crisp text/icons (even if I refresh the page or clear my cache).  But if I open a new Chrome tab while my external monitor is unplugged and navigate to the same website, the text and icons are suddenly blurry (see below).  I've reproduced this on other machines.  What might be causing this?  The problem doesn't seem limited to FontAwesome, as you can see the text bulk up too.

[image]

For what it's worth, neither Safari nor Firefox seem to have any issues.

Google Chrome        25.0.1364.172 (Official Build 187217) 
OS        Mac OS X 
WebKit        537.22 (@145275)
JavaScript        V8 3.15.11.17
Flash        11.6.602.180
User Agent        Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is going on specifically, but sometimes odd browser specific font rendering issues go away when the following CSS is used. Try adding this to a global css file included on the page.

```
html, body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```